# From Swiftui, can the message from whatsapp directly be sent using UIApplication.shared.open

Tags: swiftui, whatsapp, uiapplication

I managed to access whatsapp from swiftui with code snippet:

```
let urlWhats = "https://wa.me/55555123456/?text=hello"
if let urlString = urlWhats.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
  if let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: urlString) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(whatsappURL as URL) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(whatsappURL as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

It opens whatsapp, and writes "hello" in the input field.
But the message is not sent yet.
I have to actively press the "send" button (blue with white aeroplane) in whatsapp so send the message.
Is there a possibility that the send-action is done automatically?

Comment: I sure hope there isn't! You would not want a random app to send whatever messages they want on behalf of you, would you?

Comment: @Sweeper: makes sense. When I think of it, I already wondered that there is no explicit permission-action from whatsapp to the app accessing it (with above code any app can access whatsapp)

Comment: At best, you'd be able to use an SDK or API to do this, in the same way you can't send a message via iMessage but you can open up a draft message in iMessage for the user to take action on.